# How can HTML <output> element changes trigger further events?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

## Details

I have an example, where input and output elements are on the same site.

1. The `<output>` element value is generated
2. The `<input>` element value is given by the user
3. There is another `<output>` element, where the 1. and 2. elements product are shown.

The example should be event-driven.

- If the user types in an input, the Product must change.
- If the user-generated a new number, the Product must also change.

## Problem:

- Only the Typed parameter can cause a change in the Product element's value. There could be some reason, due to the changes of the Generated number is not triggering the product calculation.

## Question:

How could I modify my example to calculate the Product in case of change the Generated number or the Typed parameter?

## Example

```js
function generate() {
  var generatedValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $("#myinput1").val(generatedValue);
  $("#myinput1").trigger("myOwnEvent");
};

$('#myinput2')[0].addEventListener('input', calculateTheProduct);
$('#myinput3')[0].addEventListener('myOwnEvent', calculateTheProduct);

function calculateTheProduct() {
  var inputGeneratedValue = $('#myinput1')[0].value;
  var inputTypedParameter = $('#myinput2')[0].value;
  var product = inputGeneratedValue * inputTypedParameter;
  $('#myinput3').val(product);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inputClass {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.typeInput {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Generated number:</label>
  <output id="myinput1" class="form-control inputClass">
        0
  </output>
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Typed parameter:</label>
  <input id="myinput2" class="form-control inputClass typeInput" value="0">
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput3">Product:</label>
  <output id="myinput3" class="form-control inputClass" value="0">
        0
  </output>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , why not simply call `calculateTheProduct()` function inside `generate()` function ?

Comment: @Swati This could solve the problem which I showed in my described example but I need to find an event-based/event-controlled solution for this task. The main question of me is what I referred: How is it possible to initiate the event triggering of HTML elements properly in this short example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the [jquery API about the triggering](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/), I realized a solution:

I had a problem with in my example code in this line:

```
$('#myinput3')[0].addEventListener('myOwnEvent', calculateTheProduct);
```

1. There is a typo because of the HTML id `#myinput3`

This id should be referred to as the HTML element `#myinput1` Although this is not solving my problem on its own.

2. I had to replace the `addEventListener(...)` with the `on(...)` attachment mechanism.

Working replacement:

```
$('#myinput1').on('myOwnEvent', calculateTheProduct);
```

Here is the working example:

```js
function generate() {
  var generatedValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $("#myinput1").val(generatedValue);
  $("#myinput1").trigger("myOwnEvent");
};

$('#myinput2')[0].addEventListener('input', calculateTheProduct);
$('#myinput1').on('myOwnEvent', calculateTheProduct);

function calculateTheProduct() {
  var inputGeneratedValue = $('#myinput1')[0].value;
  var inputTypedParameter = $('#myinput2')[0].value;
  var product = inputGeneratedValue * inputTypedParameter;
  $('#myinput3').val(product);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inputClass {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.typeInput {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Generated number:</label>
  <output id="myinput1" class="form-control inputClass">
        0
  </output>
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Typed parameter:</label>
  <input id="myinput2" class="form-control inputClass typeInput" value="0">
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput3">Product:</label>
  <output id="myinput3" class="form-control inputClass" value="0">
        0
  </output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function generate() {
    var generatedValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    $("#myinput1").val(generatedValue);
    $('#myinput2').trigger("change");
  };

  $('#myinput2').change(calculateTheProduct);
  $("#generate").click(generate);

  function calculateTheProduct() {
    $('#myinput3').val(parseInt($("#myinput1").val()) * parseInt($('#myinput2').val()));
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inputClass {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.typeInput {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button id="generate">Generate</button>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Generated number:</label>
  <output id="myinput1" class="form-control inputClass">
        0
  </output>
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput1">Typed parameter:</label>
  <input id="myinput2" class="form-control inputClass typeInput" value="0">
</div>

<div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
  <label for="myinput3">Product:</label>
  <output id="myinput3" class="form-control inputClass" value="0">
        0
  </output>
</div>
```

This will generate a random number and if there is a Type value, it will calculate the product. If the User changes the type, it will also calculate the product.

As you have no control over what the User may enter, using `parseInt()` can be important. JS will auto-cast to Int to complete the Math. So it's not needed and it's advised to cast the value properly.

Comment: The problem with this solution: "Typed parameter" initiates the calculation of Product only after the cursor is out of the input element. In my example, the change of the "Typed parameter" caused an immediate result although the "Generated number" was incorrect (remained the previous)